# Hiding image and showing text area when hovering with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a div, containing an image, and another div below it for description, am aligning them on top of each other with flexbox, however I have a hidden div that I want to show in place of the image when I hover over the tile, but currently my code is just not working and am unable to give this div the full height of the area on hover. Here's my code:

```css
:root{
  --colorOrange: #ef5b2b;
  --colorGrey: #f5f5f5;
  --colorBlue: #0a2756;
}

.presenter {
  width: 23%;
  max-height: 320px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.presenter img{
  width: 100%;
}

.presenter-solid{
  background: var(--colorBlue);
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Poppins;
  display:none;
}
.presenter:hover img{
  display:none;
}
.presenter:hover .presenter-solid{
  display:block;
  height: 100%;

}
```

```html
<div class="presenter">
      <div class="presenter-image-holder">
        <img src="https://cdn2.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/80/91/person-gray-photo-placeholder-little-boy-vector-22808091.jpg" />
        <div class="presenter-solid">
          <span>TOM CRUISE</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="presenter-role">
        <span class="role-name">Hollywood Actor</span>
      </div>
</div>
```

It's also giving me a flicker effect when trying to hover. How can I fix my code? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: with your archtiecture, you would need JS. You can only apply :hover to the same element or its children. But not to siblings or parents.

Comment: But I am doing the hover on the presenter container itself, hiding the image and then showing something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center` to center the text.

```css
:root{
  --colorOrange: #ef5b2b;
  --colorGrey: #f5f5f5;
  --colorBlue: #0a2756;
}

.presenter {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.presenter-image-holder {
  position: relative; /* this must be added to the parent element */
  width: 250px; /* width of the image box */
  height: 250px; /* height of the image box */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.presenter img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.presenter-solid{
  background: var(--colorBlue);
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Poppins;
  display:none;
}
.presenter:hover img{
  display:none;
}
.presenter:hover .presenter-solid{
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* to vertically center the text */
  justify-content: center; /* to horizontally center the text */
}
```

```html
<div class="presenter">
    <div class="presenter-image-holder">
        <img src="https://cdn2.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/80/91/person-gray-photo-placeholder-little-boy-vector-22808091.jpg" />
        <div class="presenter-solid">
            <span>TOM CRUISE</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="presenter-role">
        <span class="role-name">Hollywood Actor</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to set the height on the container which I was missing.